# Magit: magit-merge-squash

Tags: magit, git

When I was researching the best way to merge a feature branch with a lot of WIP commits I came across squashing and rebasing however when looking how to do this in magit I found this sentence in the magit documentation on the magit-merge-squash command:

> Instead of this command you should probably use a command from the apply popup.

Why is that the case? Is it considered bad practice? If so what would be the correct way?

Comment: Probably https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3348#issuecomment-361056697 explains this

Comment: When you do it the way tarsius describes it. Does it then squash all the commits into one commit? I was thinking about using the git merge --squash command because I often have small commits like "Fix typo" in the feature branch which I don't really need in the master branch. It somehow feels cleaner to just have a single commit with "add feature x" to add a new feature without all the WIP commits.

Comment: `A a` does `git cherry-pick --no-commit`, so you get the changes without any commits.

Comment: I often have small commits like "Fix typo" in the feature branch which I don't really need in the master branch...' Another way to deal with that is to use fixup commits and rebasing.  Magit makes this convenient with commands like `magit-commit-instant-fixup`.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I will have to do a few tests to see which way makes more sense in my workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after trying out the suggestions and reading a bit more (especially, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263164/why-squash-git-commits-for-pull-requests) I came to the conclusion that despite what the documentation says the command magit-merge-squash seems to be the command I want to use when merging a feature branch into master.

Thanks all for your help!